# how to retrieve installed apps with icon in them

Tags: android, android-intent

Below given are the codes in the java and xml file which I have used to retrieve a list of apps from the phone. However it does not retrieve the icon of the apps together with it. Could anyone provide the solution preferably based on the given codes as to how I could go about achieving the objective of retrieving icons for the apps? Help would be much appreciated

xml File:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private ListView lView;
 private ArrayList results;
 List<ResolveInfo> list;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    results = new ArrayList();
    lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) 
    {
        results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
    lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
}
```

Comment: you mean rInfo.getIconResource() return 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

try with this code :

```
 PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); 
 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
 mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 final List<ResolveInfo> apps = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
 for ( int i=0;i<apps.size() ; i++){
    ResolveInfo info = apps.get(i);
    CharSequence lActTitle = info.loadLabel(manager);
    Drwable d = info.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to fetch the icon of the application, then you should use the following code,

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private ListView lView;
        private ArrayList results;
        List<ResolveInfo> list;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        results = new ArrayList();
        lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) 
        {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            // Add the Following line in your code.
            Drawable icon = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
        }
        lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
}
```

**Edit-**

Take a look at one of my projects code,

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**FetchApplicationsActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class FetchApplicationsActivity extends Activity {

    TextView data;
    ImageView image1;
    LinearLayout holdlayout;
    View l1;
    private ArrayList results;
    List<ResolveInfo> list;
    TextView result;
    String str = "";
    Drawable icon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        l1 = findViewById(R.id.Layout1);


        results = new ArrayList();
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            str = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString()
                    + "\n";
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                    .toString());
            Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                    .loadLabel(pm).toString());
            icon = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            holdlayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            holdlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            data = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            data.setText(str);
            image1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image1.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
            ((ViewGroup) holdlayout).addView(image1);
            ((ViewGroup) holdlayout).addView(data);
            ((ViewGroup) l1).addView(holdlayout);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well the variable rInfo is underlined in red. Is there anything specific that have to be done in order to resolve that?

Comment: the outcome doesn't change. Do I have to edit anything in the xml file or that something about the Drawable has to be done?

Comment: Well have changed all instances of ListView to ImageView in both the xml and java file and this particular line "lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));" has error in the setAdapter with error message "The method setAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type ImageView" with one solution asking me to add cast to IView and nothing worked despite having added cast. Is there anything I did wrongly?

Comment: No, its not like that. Wait, I'll post code from my project. Have a look at it.